# MySQL "not in" with COUNT() not working correctly

Tags: php, mysql

I wanted to run a simple query to throw up all the rows of Table `'tmp'`, that do not have `"yes"` in the column `'post_removed'`

I tried using:

```
SELECT COUNT(post_id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT post_id FROM tmp WHERE post_removed = 'yes')) AS total FROM tmp
```

This is instead throwing a syntax error. Google search led me to forums where people were saying that MySQL does not support NOT IN and something extremely complex needs to be used. Am i able to Count each Row, that doesnt have the `'yes'` in the `post_removed` column?

For the column itself, it has 2 states, either `not_set` (default) and `yes` (meaning removed, so do not count query)

Comment: Questions like this should come with a proper explanation of your data model/table structure first of all. Why is there a subquery in play here to begin with? Why is DISTINCT necessary?

Comment: MySQL _support_ `NOT IN` but the way you use it is not according to what MySQL _accept_ as a valid usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL supports `NOT IN` clause, as mentioned in their [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html).

Your query syntax is incorrect. Based on your requirement,

> Am i able to Count each Row, that doesnt have the 'yes' in the post_removed column?

Try use this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM tmp
WHERE post_removed != 'yes'
```

If there are duplicate values of `post_id`, then you can apply `DISTINCT` to get unique values

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(post_id))
FROM tmp
WHERE post_removed != 'yes'
```

Or performing `GROUP BY` will results the same, even you can get `post_removed` for each `post_id`

```
SELECT post_id, COUNT(*)
FROM tmp
WHERE post_removed != 'yes'
GROUP BY post_id
```

If the `tmp` table has many rows, it's better if you put an `INDEX` on `post_removed` column.

Answer (score 1):

I would try this way.

```
SELECT COUNT(post_id) AS total 
FROM tmp WHERE post_id NOT IN 
(SELECT DISTINCT post_id FROM tmp WHERE post_removed = 'yes'))
```

Though if the table is big then **NOT IN** will perform poorly

Answer (score 1):

you can try with multiple options

```
SELECT COUNT(POST_ID)
FROM TMP
WHERE POST_ID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT post_id FROM tmp WHERE post_removed = 'yes')
```

OR

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(post_id))
FROM tmp
WHERE post_removed != 'yes'
```